# Strategy Pattern without allocating new objects

Tags: java

I have an android game that has many different types of enemies that are all of the same class  (so that I can have a single object Pool).  When these enemies are constructed, they are given a variety of different properties at runtime, including which behavior algorithm to follow.  Currently, it looks something like this:

```
public MoveableEntity build(float positionX, float positionY, MoveableEntityType type,
        int moveLogic, MoveableEntityType weaponType,
        int firePattern, int fireLogic) {

            //Take all the passed in arguments and build an entity

    }
```

Right now in the game update loop, each entity goes through several managers which check which type of logic the entity is running, and dictates its behavior:

```
public void updateEntity(MoveableEntity e) {
    switch (e.getiLogic()) {

    case STRAIGHT_LINE_MOVEMENT:
        straightLineMovement(e);
        break;
    case RANDOM_MOVING_LEFT:
        randomMovingLeft(e);
        break;
    case ADVANCE_THEN_RETREAT:
        advanceThenRetreat(e);
        break;
    case RUSH_THEN_RETREAT:
        rushThenRetreat(e);
        break;
                   //lots of logic types
            }
```

This pattern has become fairly prevalent throughout the game (movement logic, choosing how/when to attack, etc.).  I considered using something like the strategy pattern so I could say something like:

```
public MoveableEntity build(float positionX, float positionY, MoveableEntityType type,
    MoveLogic moveLogic...) {

    this.moveLogic = moveLogic;
        //Take all the passed in arguments and build an entity

}

public void update() {
    //do some updating

   //execute assigned AI
   moveLogic.execute(this);

   //other stuff
  }
```

Which would be great, but I would end up creating tons of extra classes for all the different types of AI components that an entity uses.  Basically my question boils down to:  Is there a way to implement an OO friendly solution in this scenario that won't require me to create/destroy lots of new objects (and thus potentially hurting performance)?  Are several switch statements in this scenario ok?  What should be my approach?

Comment: What's the specific problem: creating bunch of class implementations or creating new instances of these class implementations?

Comment: The instances seem like a larger problem.  Since multiple entities often use the same logic, I would end up having around 40 different singletons at all times, which seems sort of gross.  If they weren't singletons they would be de-allocated often, and if the GC runs during the game it will likely be pretty noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Template design pattern instead. By doing that you can have common code in super-classes and just implement the differences in the subclasses.

Additionally I think that creating a lot of classes is much better than a clusterfuck of spaghetti code. It will become hard to manage and impossible to debug in the long run. Just create a new folder and put all you AI components in there.

Comment: I think this is what I will have to end up doing--It just seems messy to create so many singleton classes.

Comment: But how long will his class with the switch cases become? Every time Fenster wants to add a new AI component he has to look up every Switch-statement and add code there. If he implements an object oriented solution all he has to do is to extend the abstract super class, implement the methods and he will be done. By using the template method he can group similiar types of AI to abstract classes and the risk for error will decrease a lot, since there wont be much copied code.

Comment: @Fenster : LuiggiMendoza and Sane both have very valid and solid points. But I think something is wrong with the game design. Enemies can be very similar or enemies can be much different from each other. Separate them and create different enemy classes..rather than having a giant enemy class or having a ton of enemy classes.

Comment: A possible solution is not using plain inheritance but using composition as well. For example, if a unit (enemy, ally or whatever) has to move to the right, then is a `RightMovementBehavior` that should be set as a `MovementBehavior` field in the `MoveableEntity` class.

Comment: @SajalDutta Is your point that he should implement an interface instead of an abstract class in his subclasses? That works, but the risk for duplicated code increases dramatically.

Comment: @Sane not at all. In fact, this is covered in the first chapter of Head First Design Patterns book.

Comment: No, I am not asking for any OOP pattern here. Create POJO's of different enemies with similar behavior. I would not even ask to have setters/getters all over the place either. In mid range mobile device, OOP is not any charm.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the input.  I originally had many different classes for enemies, but ran into the problem of having to create different object pools for each type.  I'll take a look at grouping them more generally so that I won't have to create a new pool as often.

Comment: Also, since enemies of the same type can have different AI depending on the situation, using composition is a must.  ATM I've just been passing in a type # (hence the switch statement) to each enemy, but I'll look at some sort of singleton class I can use.

Comment: @Fenster Try not creating new instances on update/render..rather create them beforehand and manipulate their positions..if one "dies"/leaves the screen..update its position..this way you won't have any sudden fps drops..

Answer (score 0):

You should group enemies with similar behaviors.

1. Say you have an laser_alien enemy type which has some type of movements (e.g. some move in spiral order, some zigzag, etc) and throws laser bullets along the way.
2. Now you have another type of enemies whose specialty is carrying some type of magnet that pulls the player closer to them so the player will lose health. That type of enemies say move only in one direction either left to right or in reverse.

Separate those two types of enemies and then create instances of those enemies in your game world. This way you can easily maintain your different enemy classes. Say you now need to add another type of movement in enemy at point one above, in that case you don't have to touch number 2 above. If you have so many varities you will be left with a huge enemy class that will be eventually a pain to maintain. I would tell you to implement everything in proper OOP way but it will affect your game performance.

And please have corresponding update methods in your enemy classes. Don't write update code in your game world class. In game world, update method should be as simple as-

```
for(LaserEnemy lEnemy : laserEnemies){
   lEnemy.update(deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that I'd have to end up creating many different object pools (depending on how specific I was in grouping enemies).  Also, enemies of the same class can still have different AI routines, which is why I would have run into the original problem with this method anyway.

Comment: @Fenster As I mentioned in another comment, I believe something is off with the game design. You cannot have more than 50 enemies in a given time on a mobile device. It will look either pretty bad or player witll not be able to move. So, if you have 20 enemies in a given time on the screen and you have 5 types of enemies, then create only 4 instances each of all the 5 types. I don't see how this will make your game slower. Again, a very good game design is the soultion.

Comment: *You cannot have more than 50 enemies in a given time on a mobile device.* looks like you have to play more mobile device games :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Trust me I play a lot as I am making one and it helps. But really I don't see more than 50 (maybe a little more :)) in a given time..say it a tower defense..worms..jetpack joyride..endless running game..or startegy game like arcane legend..I simply did not..and I observe more than playing..as I said it helps me understand why..heck..you won't even see coins are placed in jetpack joyride when laser are there..that is why it is so fast..

Comment: Also, That is how updates work--the AI code isn't in the gameworld class, it is in a self-contained AI class that is passed into each entity when it is built.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the singleton pattern for MoveLogic classes, so instead of using

```
this.moveLogic = new MoveLogic();
```

You can use:

```
this.moveLogic = MoveLogic.getInstance();
```

Thus only allocating one MoveLogic object for each MoveLogic class.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the creation of tons of extra classes, you can create a [factory class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) of move logic strategies.

```
public class MoveLogicFactory{

    public static MoveLogic createStraightLineMovementLogic(){
        //return a an anonymous inner class of type MoveLogic
        return new MoveLogic(){
            //apply your codes for this specific move logic
        }
    }

    public static MoveLogic createRandomMovingLeftLogic(){
        //... do the same as the first method
    }

    public static MoveLogic createAdvanceThenRetreatLogic(){
        //... do the same as the first method
    }

    public static MoveLogic createRushThenRetreatLogic(){
        //... do the same as the first method
    }
}
```